# Selenium 2.32, Java 1.6.0_07, IE Webdriver (32 and 64 Bit), IE9 - getWindowHandles returns only one browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium 2.32, Java JDK 1.6.0_07, IE9 with Windows 7. Here is the problem

1. When i use IE WebDriver 32 Bit and click on a link which opens a new browser containing PDF, the PDF is opened in the browser itself which is fine, but the new browser is not identified when i use driver.getWindowHandles(). It always returns only the parent window. When i use the same code with IE8, it works perfectly fine and i am able to get the URL of the new browser.
2. I thought since it is Windows 7 and IE9, i should use IE Webdriver 64 bit and so i used IE Webdriver version 2.32.3 (64 Bit). With this webdriver, when i click on the link, the new browser pops up but the PDF is not opened in the browser and instead it is opened as a separate PDF file. Even in this case, the new browser is not identified and driver.getWindowHandles() returns only one browser.

Not just the PDF browsers but also the normal browsers are not returned by driver.getWindowHandles()

I am using a wait of 10 seconds for the new browser to load and so the there is no load/sync issue.
I want to identify the new browser and get the URL of the new browser. Please help.

Comment: Any answer or suggestion on this please...

Comment: For a sanity check, I would recommend you write a very simple popup window test that does not involve the .pdf or any other mime-type except text/html .  Here is a sample site I made that you can test against: http://djangofan.github.io/html-test-site/site/w1.html

Comment: I tried it but still the same. I observed one thing as well. 
1. IEDriverServer is invoked. A new browser is opened and i redirect this browser to the required URL. This browser is the WebDriver.
2. In this WebDriver, there is the link which opens the new browser. Ideally this new browser should also be the WebDriver and only then the driver.getWindowHandles() will identify this new browser.
3. I found that the new browser which is opened after clicking on the link available in the parent driver is not a WebDriver.

Comment: I found that the new browser is not a webdriver by the below observation - This is because after clicking on Stop in Eclipse IDE, i clicked manually on links in the parent browser and it did not redirect or opened a new browser. Instead the mouse pointer got changed to stop icon when i click on any of the links. Meaning the actual driver does not recognizes the manual clicks or any events. But when i did the manual clicks in the new browser, it redirected me and was recognizing the clicks and other events, Any idea on why the new browser that got opened is not a WebDriver in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are making things too complicated.   From your comments, it does not seem you are doing things the "typical" and "recommended" way.  If you are following advice, then you are doing it the slightly harder route.  My advice is still to simplify further.

If I were to guess on your issue though: I notice that you say you are using "IEDriverServer".  That tells me that you may be improperly using WebDriver.  When you are using a Grid Hub and a separate Grid Node ( see my link here for sample launch instructions: https://gist.github.com/djangofan/5174433 )  then you should be invoking RemoteWebDriver rather than WebDriver, like so (or similar):

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver (
     new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), 
     DesiredCapabilities.firefox()
);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:
Root cause: On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode".

Hope it works for you.